# Small Space & Apartment Brewing: Mashing

Tags: process, mash, small-space, apartment

### Given the limited space of an apartment, how do you mash in cramped quarters?

#### Do not consider budget to be a factor.

This is the second question in a series of discussions about small-space brewing.  Please keep the discussion limited to **mashing**.

See also: [Equipment Storage](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1330/small-space-apartment-brewing-equipment-storage) | [Steeping](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1332/small-space-apartment-brewing-steeping) | [Boiling](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1333/small-space-apartment-brewing-boiling) | [Chilling](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1334/small-space-apartment-brewing-the-chill) | [Fermentation](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1335/small-space-apartment-brewing-fermentation) | [Packaging](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1336/small-space-apartment-brewing-packaging) | [Cellaring](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1337/small-space-apartment-brewing-cellaring)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I go back and forth between a 10 gallon rectangular cooler with a bazooka screen and a 5 gallon cylindrical Igloo cooler with a false bottom. The igloo is the way to go if your kitchen is really tiny, in my opinion, as it has a much smaller footprint.

I've also heard of people mashing in a pot and putting it in the oven to maintain temperature. Never tried that method, but I could see it working pretty well.

Comment: putting it in the the oven (preheated?) sounds like a good idea

Comment: Just be sure your oven works properly at low temps.  My old oven thermostat was only really accurate between 325 and 425.  I can't even set a temp below 170 on my current oven.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old thread, but I cannot believe no one answered to use the Brew in a Bag method which means you mash in your boil kettle. No extra vessel needed. You line your boil kettle with a mesh bag and when the mash is complete you remove the bag and all the grain.

This is how I brew every time now, and I don't have to store the mash tun any more.

Comment: I have done BIAB for my last couple of homebrews, and it has worked pretty well.

Answer (score 3):

I use a 5 gal. bucket with a braided s.s. hose for a filter, and attached to the spigot at the bottom. You can go here:
 http://backyardbrewer.blogspot.com/2009/12/malting-barley-in-mexico-iv-mash.html
for a picture of this.

mark

www.backyardbrewer.blogspot.com