# Small Space & Apartment Brewing: Steeping

Tags: process, steeping, small-space, apartment

### Given the limited space of an apartment, what tips do you have for steeping specialty grain?

#### Do not consider budget to be a factor.

This is the third question in a series of discussions about small-space brewing.  Please keep the discussion limited to **steeping**

See also: [Equipment Storage](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1330/small-space-apartment-brewing-equipment-storage) | [Mashing](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1331/small-space-apartment-brewing-mashing) | [Boiling](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1333/small-space-apartment-brewing-boiling) | [Chilling](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1334/small-space-apartment-brewing-the-chill) | [Fermentation](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1335/small-space-apartment-brewing-fermentation) | [Packaging](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1336/small-space-apartment-brewing-packaging) | [Cellaring](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1337/small-space-apartment-brewing-cellaring)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep it proportional.

I haven't discovered a perfect ratio for pounds of steeping grains to steeping water volume, but I have learned to be wary of using more than a few pounds in just a couple gallon steep.

Previously, I used a grain bag with 2-5 lbs of specialty grains, depending on the recipe, in a 8 qt steep.

Recently, though, I've started adding the milled grains directly to the water, without a bag. After steeping them for ~30 minutes, I use a second pot/kettle and conical colander with some cheese cloth to filter out the grains.
After transferring the wort to the second pot (where I will add the extract, hops, etc. for the full boil), I use a couple quarts of hot water to sparge the specialty grains (still in the colander).

I really enjoy the newer process, because I feel like my grains get better exposure and better add to the flavor profile.