# Small Space & Apartment Brewing: Packaging

Tags: process, bottling, kegging, small-space, apartment

### Given the limited space of an apartment, how do you bottle & keg?

#### Do not consider budget to be a factor.

This is the seventh question in a series of discussions about small-space brewing.  Please keep the discussion limited to **packaging**.

See also: [Equipment Storage](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1330/small-space-apartment-brewing-equipment-storage) | [Mashing](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1331/small-space-apartment-brewing-mashing) | [Steeping](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1332/small-space-apartment-brewing-steeping) | [Boiling](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1333/small-space-apartment-brewing-boiling) | [Chilling](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1334/small-space-apartment-brewing-the-chill) | [Fermentation](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1335/small-space-apartment-brewing-fermentation) | [Cellaring](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1337/small-space-apartment-brewing-cellaring)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what this question is asking.  are you looking for how one packages beer, or how one stores the packages of beer.  I am going to try and answer both.

I am very fortunate to have an understand fiance that doesn't mind beer stuff strewn about but I'm sure I'm the exception and not the rule.

I typically do a mix of bottles and kegs depending on the availability of my limited equipment.  for bottles I have a series of milk crates that hold ~20 bottles and stack as high as one wants.  It's a great space saver for bottles. I stack these, in the nooks and crannies of my apartment that have enough dead space.

one of my closets typically only holds dress shirts and pants, so I have some space on the bottom for storing kegs and associated hardware. I should also mention that this closet is open to the unheated cellar so it stays cool all year.  if I have people over or want to have something out of the kegs I typically have to pull everything out, so I try and keep most of my liquid assets in bottles.

my apartment poses a couple challenges to bottling.  I have a tiny kitchen with no counter space and not enough floorspace for two people to be working on bottling.  I typically take my brew bucket and fill it with star-san and submerge bottles in my livingroom.  my helper passes the cleaned bottles to me in the kitchen for filling.  We lay down a bunch of towels to catch drips and such.